# liferay change page title dynamically

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-velocity

I'm trying to change the title of the page, but the method `PortalUtil.setPageTitle("title", request);` is not working from the jsp. I also tried in the `doView` method.

My second attempt was throught servletrequest:

In `doView` I wrote

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest));
httpRequest.setAttribute("hola", "hola");
```

And in the portal normal I tried with:

```
#set ($holas =$request.get('attributes').get('hola'))
#set ($holas2 = $request.getSession().getAttribute("hola"))

$holas    
$holas2
```

but Velocity only shows `$holas $holas2`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I got it wrong in my first attempt - thus I've replaced the previous answer with this one: Add [this code](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/util/PortalUtil.html#setPageTitle%28java.lang.String,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29) to your JSP or doView:

```
<% 
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.setPageTitle("Honk", request); 
%>
```

Comment: Javascript is not an option, because Google doesn't read js. Could you please explain the other way? is it possible in doView inside XXXportlet.java?

Answer (score 0):

In your jsp you should try

```
<%
layout.setTitle("title");
%>
```

layout is an Layout object generated by jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code,

```
String title = (String)renderRequest.getAttribute("title");
HtmlPageTitleUtil.setHtmlTitle(title, request, true);
```

Pass title attribute from the controller or you can use static text as well.
Import the above utility class as well as,

```
<portlet:defineObjects />
<theme:defineObjects />
```

this to jsp and its done.